# Recursive wrapper that adds a specific function applied to every objects in a container of container in c++

Tags: c++

I would like to make a wrapper to a specific container (or a container of container) class such that the wrapper (1) inherits all the functions of the parent class and (2) adds a specific function that applies to all the elements.

For example, I want to add `bar` function that takes an object whose class is `Destination` on the container types that have `bar(Destination)`. The first thing that comes to my mind is as below:

```cpp
// I want as Enablebar<vector<Foo>> for any `Foo` that is guaranteed to have `void bar(Destination)`.
template <class Iterable> class Enablebar : public Iterable {
public:
    void bar(const Destination &dest) {
        for (auto &item : *this) {
            item.bar(dest);
        }
    }
};
```

So that I can enable `bar` functions on various containers in a project. (I cannot modify or touch the definitions of the containers, and there are many of such containers).

The problem is that I would like to use it also on container of container, or even container of container of container (i.e., `vector<vector<list<Foo>>>`), where `Foo` and `vector` are classes that I cannot touch or modify. So I just use it like `Enablebar<vector<Enablebar<vector<Enablebar<list<Foo>>>>`.

Question: is it possible to write a somewhat recursive, smart wrapper that replaces `Enablebar` that I can use something like:
`EnablebarSmartly<vector<vector<list<Foo>>>>`? I'm not having a problem with `EnableBar`; just out of curiosity.

Comment: It is not a good idea to inherit from standard containers. Write a standalone function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 2 overloads, you might do something like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto bar(T& item, const Destination &dest)
-> decltype(item.bar(dest), void())
{
    item.bar(dest);
}

template <typename Container>
auto bar(Container& c, const Destination &dest)
-> decltype(c.begin(), void()) // Check container, just use `begin` here
{
    for (auto &item : c) {
        bar(item, dest);
    }
}
```

With C++20, You might use requires instead of SFINAE

```cpp
template <typename T>
void bar(T& item, const Destination &dest)
requires(requires{ item.bar(dest);})
{
    item.bar(dest);
}

template <typename Container>
void bar(Container& c, const Destination &dest)
requires(requires{c.begin(); /* Check container, just use `begin` here*/ })
{
    for (auto &item : c) {
        bar(item, dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, btw, how the type `decltype(c.begin(), void())` is determined? Is it a kind of SFINAE? It's hard for me to decipher the expression even after reading the reference in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype.

Comment: It is indeed for SFINAE (discarded if `item.bar(dest)` is wrong in immediate context). Inside the `decltype`,  I use comma operator, type is so the type of the last expression (`void()`, so `void`).

Comment: In C++20, with requires, it might be `void bar(T& item, const Destination &dest) requires(requires{ item.bar(dest); }) {item.bar(dest);}`